# Tracing an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get this to work, but I must have made a mistake somewhere. This is the Delegate class (snipped down) as per the C headers:

```
@protocol PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate <NSObject>

@required

/*!
    @brief Delegate method for startTransaction. 
    @param transResponse - Contains all the transaction response info from the gateway
 */
-(void)transactionComplete :(PaymentEngineTransactionResponse *)transResponse;
@optional

/*!
    @brief Delegate method for device connected. The method gets called when the device is connected
 */
-(void)deviceConnected;

/*!
  @brief Delegate method for device disconnected. The method gets called when the device is disconnected
 */
-(void)deviceDisconnected;

@end
```

For this, I have:

```
// @interface PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
[Protocol]
interface PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate
{
    [Abstract]
    [Export("transactionComplete:")]
    void TransactionComplete(PaymentEngineTransactionResponse transResponse);

    [Export("deviceConnected")]
    void DeviceConnected();

    [Export("deviceDisconnected")]
    void DeviceDisconnected();
}
```

Then for the PaymentEngineMiddleware class, the header has this:

```
@interface PaymentEngineMiddleware : NSObject

+ (PaymentEngineMiddleware *) getInstance;

@property(nonatomic, strong) id<PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate> delegate;

//------------------------------Device Methods------------------------------

/*!
    @brief This method must be called before starting any transaction. Use it to connect to a device.
    @param deviceName The name of the device such as icmp or castle
    @param setDelegate Sets to self

 */
-(void)setDevice :(NSString *)deviceName :(id)setDelegate;

@end
```

And for that, I have:

```
// @interface PaymentEngineMiddleware : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Protocol]
interface PaymentEngineMiddleware
{
    // +(id)getInstance;
    [Static]
    [Export("getInstance")]
    PaymentEngineMiddleware GetInstance { get; }

    [Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export("setDevice:setDelegate:")]
    void SetDevice(string deviceName, PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate setDelegate);
}
```

In code, when I try to call the "middleware.SetDevice('name', this);" where this is a class that inherits from the delegate, I get the exception.

Is there anything obvious that I missed or got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your selector for `setDevice` method is wrong.**

The proper selector for `-(void)setDevice :(NSString *)deviceName :(id)setDelegate` method is `setDevice::`. This is because the second parameter in this method doesn't have an external name.

The final entry for your binding should look like this

```
[Export("setDevice::")]
void SetDevice(string deviceName, PaymentEngineMiddlewareDelegate setDelegate);
```

You can read more about how the methods signatures in Objective-C are constructed in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also look in the Storyboard file for the component action in properties which is not implemented in the code.

in my case I have given touch insideup action for button in storyboard file but not implemented that in a code. after implementing this issue is no more.